# Loop through divs with the same class, collect their values and multiply them

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements with the same class containing decimal numbers (precision 2) for example "2.25". So lets say I have n number of elements with the same class containing different numbers. What I want to do is to collect the values of these elements and then multiply them. So for example we have 2.50, 2.00, 3.50 - I need to multiply 2.50*2.00*3.50. What I've managed to do so far is to collect the values of the elements like so:

```
<span class='test'>2.50</span>
<span class='test'>2.00</span>
<span class='test'>3.50</span>

$('.test').each(function() {
multiplied = ??? - thats what i dont know how to multiply them
then I append the result to a div
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum=1;

$('.test').each(function(index,item) {

  var val = parseFloat($(item).html());

  if(!isNaN(val))
  {
     sum = sum * val;
  }
});
$("#resultDivIdHere").html(sum);
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xoduyo/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: What's the preceding comma? Typo? `function(,ndex,item) {...`?

Comment: typo! fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you both. I have a question not much related to this exact subject:
How safe it is to use jquery, data attributes and .html() in order to manipulate data and store it in a database? In other words - Is it safe to use these methods ? Can a user do something to manipulate these numbers in order to take advantage ? For example if these numbers are points in a game - would the user be able to do something to take advantage and gain more points than intended ?

Answer (score 0):

Or just reduce

```
var total = $('.test').toArray().reduce(function(a,b) {
    return (a.innerHTML || a) * b.innerHTML;
});
```